# How to remove cuda-9.0 and install cuda-8.0 instead?

Tags: 16.04, apt, nvidia, package-management, cuda

I've been working on installing CUDA for TensorFlow usage.

I realized that cuda-9.0 has been just released today, and I accidentally downloaded and dpkged it, and installed it on my machine.

I realized that cuda-9.0 is not yet compatible with TensorFlow so I had to uninstall it with:

```
sudo apt autoremove cuda
```

Which did remove everything, but now whenever I try to install cuda-8.0, after downloading and `dpkg`ing, it prompts me to install cuda-9.0 instead.

Now I know I can work around this with:

```
sudo apt-get install cuda-8-0
```

But I also need to install the patch, which can't be done this way.

I've been trying many methods to resolve this issue:

1. `sudo apt-get remove cuda-9-0-blablal`
2. Removing the apt-key of cuda-9 with:

   - `apt-key del [KEY]`

But none of these really worked.

Can someone help me out?

***UPDATE***

Right after posting this, I figured out the answer, which turned out to be simple.

I'm leaving it for others:

I was able to solve it simply, by removing cuda-9 stuff from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/cuda-9-0-local.list`

***UPDATE 2***
And now I have another problem which is after

`sudo dpkg -i cuda-8-0-blabla`

none of it appears on `sources.list.d` anymore.

Comment: Actually, I was able to solve it simply, by removing cuda-9 stuff from ```/etc/apt/sources.list.d/cuda-9-0-local.list```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I got the exact same issue and managed to fix it. First observation was that the cuda-8 related entries in sources.list.d/ were commented out, but removing these and doing the dpkg --install of the cuda-8 repo did not repopulate the sources.list.d/ entries. What worked was to purge the 'dpkg' install (/var/cuda*) manually and doing the 'dpkg --install' again.

step by step:

- `dpkg -l | grep cuda- | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -n1 sudo dpkg --purge`
- `dpkg --install cuda-repo-ubuntu*-8.0-local*.deb`
- `sudo apt-get update`
- `sudo apt-get install cuda`

Comment: I had to first do, sudo apt-get --purge remove cuda and sudo apt autoremove, so as to remove Cuda 9. Then I installed Cuda 8

Comment: I guess the cuda-repo for all the versions is the same, because when I do "sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1604_8.0.61-1_amd64.deb" then "sudo apt-get instll cuda" it tries to install version 9 still

Comment: had to use "apt-get install cuda-8.0" otherwise cuda-9 was always selected

Comment: saved my life!!

Answer (score 6):

There's actually a script in `/usr/local/cuda-9.x/bin/` which performs the uninstall process for you.

Comment: What is the name of the script?

Comment: @Magick I believe it should be something like `/usr/local/cuda-9.2/bin/uninstall_cuda_9.2.pl`.  That's what [this link](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#runfile-uninstallation) says, but I don't have this file myself.

Answer (score 3):

https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1024342/cuda-setup-and-installation/unable-to-uninstall-cuda-9-0-completely-and-install-8-0-instead/

It works for me. It might be helpful for you too.

Comment: In the end, I reinstalled Ubuntu.

Comment: This should provide with the actual commands in the answer not in a link. No matter how good a solution is it should be fully accessible from within SO.

Answer (score 2):

I had to add "--force-all" to the purge command:

```
dpkg -l | grep cuda- | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -n1 sudo dpkg --purge --force-all
```

Answer (score 2):

The above command

```
sudo apt-get install cuda-8-0
```

might have worked but does not any more!
You must change it into the following line - it is an almost undetectable difference:

```
sudo apt-get install cuda-8.0
```

The ending is not "-0" but ".0"!

Answer (score 2):

The official way is to run a uninstaller script:

[**Taken from nVidia documentation:**](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#runfile-uninstallation)

**4.6. Uninstallation**

To uninstall the CUDA Toolkit, run the uninstallation script provided in the bin directory of the toolkit. By default, go to `/usr/local/cuda-9.1/bin` and run

```
$ sudo ./uninstall_cuda_9.1.pl
```

Comment: I don't have any such file (cuda-10.2). Also I think this is only the official way when you installed cude using a .run file, not when you use a .deb package manager.

Answer (score 1):

As answered by @Beef earlier:

1. `dpkg -l | grep cuda- | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -n1 sudo dpkg --purge`
2. `dpkg --install cuda-repo-ubuntu*-8.0-local*.deb`
3. `sudo apt-get update`
4. `sudo apt-get install cuda`

It doesn't work now. I realized step 1 doesn't remove cuda completely. I still had to do:

- `sudo apt-get remove cuda-*`
  in order to remove my `cuda-9-1` version and others.

Additionally when you are using [deb(network)](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-80-ga2-download-archive) version or the deb(local), on doing:

```
sudo apt-get install cuda
```

It lists down cuda-9-1 the latest drivers. Refer to [here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1024342/unable-to-uninstall-cuda-9-0-completely-and-install-8-0-instead/).

The step 4 in instruction shown by @beef should be instead:

```
sudo apt-get install cuda-8-0
```